# Guess the number game in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input, while-loop

so I'm making a program where the user has 20 guesses to guess a random integer 1-1000. there are 2 different spots where I'm hung up.
1- im having a hard time getting their y/n input as part of the while loop, I want it to end when they say N/n and I want the loop to start when they say Y/y.
2- in my print function that says 'please enter guess #' , I have been trying to figure out how to get it to print the actual guess number that they are on seeing as they only get 20 guesses but I am having syntax errors

## This is a guess the number game

```
 import random
 guess = 0
 number = random.randint(1,1000)
 print(' Do you wish to play 20 guesses? (Y/N) ')
 y_n = input ()
 if y_n == 'y''Y':
```

continue

```
elif a=='n''N':
break

while guess < 20:
print('please enter guess ',', guessestaken )
guess=input()
guess=int(guess)

guessestatken = guess + 1

if guess < number:
 print('Your guess is too low')

if guess > number:
 print('Your guess is too high')

if guess==number:
 break

if guess == number:
guess = str(guessestaken)
print('CONGRATGULATIONS! You WIN ! ! !')


if guess !=number:
number=str(number)
print('Nope, the number i was thinking of was ', number, '. You Lose')
```

Answer (score 0):

So code can be cleaned to the following working version.

```
import random

while True:
    # Output loop checks if we want to continue to play
    y_n = input ('Do you wish to play 20 guesses? (Y/N)')
    if y_n != 'y' and y_n != 'Y':
        print('Okay, ending guessing game')
        break
        
    number = random.randint(1,1000)
 
    # for Loop to allow up to 20 guesses
    for guesses_taken in range(20):
        # Input allows an argument to show user prompt (no need for print prior to input)
        guess =input(f'Please enter guess (guesses so far {guesses_taken})')
        guess = int(guess)

        if guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low')
        elif guess > number:
            print('Your guess is too high')
        else:
            print('CONGRATGULATIONS! You WIN ! ! !')
            break
    else:
        print('Sorry, out of guesses')
```

Comment: thats perfect should I make the range 1,20 since number of guesses can't really be 0

Answer (score 0):

You are using some redundant checks. Firstly, `continue/break` statements are meant to be used within loops to break out of it or pass to next iteration, so using them inside if/else will do no good. Secondly, you never increase your `guess` variable so it will never break out of loop. You need to increment it in each iteration. Final code I came up with is:

```
import random
guess = 0
number = random.randint(1,1000)

print('Do you wish to play 20 guesses? (Y/N) ')
y_n = input ()
if y_n == 'y' or y_n == 'Y': # You need to use or to check for 2 different conditions
    while guess < 20:
        print('please enter guess ')
        guessestatken = int(input())

        if guessestatken < number:
            print('Your guess is too low')
        elif guessestatken > number:
            print('Your guess is too high')
        else:
            print('CONGRATGULATIONS! You WIN ! ! !')
            break

        guess += 1


# guess being 20 means user never found correct number
if guess == 20:
    print('Nope, the number i was thinking of was ', str(number), '. You Lose')
```